# Avoid for-loops when calculating grid points that are sum of vectors

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, matrix, nested-for-loop

I would like to speed up my Matlab code.
Typically I find ways to avoid for-loops to gain computation time, but I'm hitting a brick wall in this case.
I have to calculate the values in a grid of points, but calculating the value requires a logic operation and a sum over a vector, and this complicates the implementation.
This code runs in about 8 seconds on my machine:

```
clear all
% Grid
dLimsX=[-100 +100];
dLimsY=[-100 +100];
dStep=1;
[x_map, y_map]=meshgrid((dLimsX(1):dStep:dLimsX(2)),(dLimsY(1):dStep:dLimsY(2)));
nPoints_map=numel(x_map);
% Inputs
smallDistance=1e-3;
N=10e3;
scaleFactor=10;
x_input = sin(linspace(0,1,N));
y_input = cos(linspace(0,1,N));
z_input = linspace(0,1,N);
tic
A=zeros(size(x_map));
for r=1:size(x_map,1)
    y0=y_map(r,1);
    for c=1:size(x_map,2)
        x0=x_map(1,c);
        
        idxTemp = find((x0-x_input).^2+(y0-y_input).^2>smallDistance); % do not consider in the calculation the inputs too close to the point
        A(r,c) = sum( scaleFactor * z_input(idxTemp) .* (y0-y_input(idxTemp)) ./ ((x0-x_input(idxTemp)).^2 +(y0-y_input(idxTemp)).^2+eps) );
    end
end
toc
```

Comment: Speeding up code is not about removing for loops. I've seem plenty of cases where vectorized code is slower than the loop equivalent. MATLAB's loops have been getting faster and faster over the last 20 years, and they're not a significant source of slowdown any more. It is usually avoiding indexing of whole columns or rows, that makes a vectorized solution  faster. In your case, I would start by removing duplicate computations. For example, `(y0-y_input).^2` can be computed outside the inner loop. You can also leave out the `find` for a good speedup (index with the logical matrix).

Comment: Also, `clear all` is unnecessary and makes your code slower. Use `clear` if you want to delete all variables. `clear all` unloads all parsed functions from memory, meaning MATLAB will need to load and parse them again when you use them.

Answer (score 2):

Speeding up code is not about removing for loops. I've seem plenty of cases where vectorized code is slower than the loop equivalent. MATLAB's loops have been getting faster and faster over the last 20 years, and they're not a significant source of slowdown any more. For example, the following is only a factor 4 slower than `sum(x)` for summing 1 million elements:

```
y = 0;
for ii = 1:numel(x)
   y = y+x(ii);
end
```

If the computations inside the loop are more expensive, the loop overhead disappears completely.

The reason you can still get benefit out of vectorizing is that in loop code one often extracts a row or column of a matrix. This involves copying data, which is expensive. On the other hand, if vectorized code needs a large intermediate matrix, then storing that matrix in memory will be the bottleneck that makes the vectorized code significantly slower. Memory access is usually the problem.

---

To make your code faster, you should focus first on avoiding duplicate computations. For example, `(y0-y_input).^2` is computed `3*size(x_map,2)` times! (1/3 of the time for a subset of the data, but the number of points removed by the indexing is small).

Also, you should use logical indexing, and avoid the use of `find`. `A(find(condition))` is the same as `A(condition)`, but slower.

Your loop runs in ~10.5 s on my machine, this version runs in ~5.1 s:

```matlab
tic
A = zeros(size(x_map));
for r = 1:size(x_map,1)
    y0 = y_map(r,1);
    dy2 = (y0-y_input).^2;
    for c = 1:size(x_map,2)
        x0 = x_map(1,c);
        dx2 = (x0-x_input).^2;
        idxTemp = dx2 + dy2 > smallDistance; % do not consider in the calculation the inputs too close to the point
        A(r,c) = sum(scaleFactor * z_input(idxTemp) .* (y0-y_input(idxTemp)) ./ (dx2(idxTemp) + dy2(idxTemp) + eps));
    end
end
toc
```

There could be further improvements, for example avoiding the repeated computation of `y0-y_input` in the inner loop as well.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to give such informative reply.
The code you propose indeed cuts the computing time by 50-60%.
Also, the hint of removing useless repetition of calculation was an eye opener!
I'd appreciate your feedback on my proposed solution.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Cris Luengo gave me a huge hint and got me thinking about which calculations I can avoid repeating.
Avoiding recalculating `x0-x_input` and `y0-y_input`, as proposed by Cris, already cuts the computation time by 50-60%.

Furthermore, when using the code within another loop, it helped me to separate what changes and what can be calculated only once. In my case, `x0`, `x_input`, `y0`, `y_input` remain always the same; , `z_input` changes with every new iteration.
So I split the calculation in two parts: first, calculate once everything that doesn't change; second, calculate the required values.

To be able to perform the second calculation with a simple matrix multiplication, I rearranged the x-y values from a matrix (grid) to a vector.
This is what I did:

```
% Arrange x-y values in two vectors
x = x_map(:);
y = y_map(:);
nPoints = numel(x);

z_input = linspace(0,1,N)';

tic
a = zeros(nPoints,N);
for p = 1:nPoints
    x0 = x(p);
    y0 = y(p);
    dx2 = (x0-x_input).^2;
    dy2 = (y0-y_input).^2;
    idxTemp = dx2 + dy2 > smallDistance; % do not consider in the calculation the inputs too close to the point
    a(p,:) = (scaleFactor * 1 .* dy2 ./ (dx2 + dy2 + eps)) .*idxTemp;
end
toc
tic
A2 = a*z_input;
toc

% Check that the values calculated with the alternative method are correct
mean(mean(abs((A(:)-A2)./A(:))))
```

Some comments on the results:

- Original code: ~122 s on my home PC (much slower than my office PC of the original post)
- Code proposed by Cris: ~50 s
- Code above: ~75 s for the first part. ~0.6 s for the second part.
- The alternative calculation has a relative error of around 1E-17.

So in cases when the calculation is repeated multiple times it pays off to pre-calculate what doesn't change.
The drawback is a larger memory usage needed to store the variable `a`.

I'd be grateful for your feedback.